# Have Meteor update a string every second

Tags: meteor, setinterval

This is Meteor's default HTML:

```
<head>
  <title>random-test</title>
</head>

<body>
  {{> hello}}
</body>

<template name="hello">
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  {{greeting}}
  <input type="button" value="Click" />
</template>
```

And this is Meteor's default Javascript code:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.hello.greeting = function () {
    return "Welcome to random-test.";
  };

  Template.hello.events({
    'click input' : function () {
      // template data, if any, is available in 'this'
      if (typeof console !== 'undefined')
        console.log("You pressed the button");
    }
  });
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    // code to run on server at startup
  });
}
```

I changed the Javascript so I could have it update `{{greeting}}` every second:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.hello.greeting = "hi";

  Meteor.setInterval(function() {
    Session.set("greeting", "hello");
    console.log("Hi");
  }, 1000);

  Template.hello.events({
    'click input' : function () {
      // template data, if any, is available in 'this'
      if (typeof console !== 'undefined')
        console.log("You pressed the button");
    }
  });
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    // code to run on server at startup
  });
}
```

It is console.logging "hi" every second. However, it is either not updating the value of `greeting` or `Session.get` isn't updating its value as it should (according to Meteor docs).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to return the `Session.get('greeting')` in a helper:

```
Template.hello.greeting = function() {
    return Session.get('greeting');
}
```

Comment: Awesome, that worked. Now, do you happen to know if I can do that from the server-side?

Comment: Not that easily. What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to have my server generate a new value for `{{greeting}}` every second so that it's the same for all clients. I read online I might need Collections for this so I'll look into them.

Comment: Either that, or `client-call` package. But if you want to have it the same on all clients, creating a collection and putting an object inside is a better idea.

Comment: Another approach is to use a publication.  All the clients could subscribe to the publication, so they'll get the same greeting.  Take a look at the 'counts-by-room' example in the docs to see how to directly control a published record

Answer (score 0):

Having `Template.hello.greeting = "hi";` makes the template not dependent on `Session.get('greeting')`, so changes to that "session variable" won't cause any re-renderings. Or what do you expect to happen?